# How to avoid ggplot grouping individual country observations in R

Tags: ggplot2, time-series, grouping

I have a tbl as shown below

```
head(officialData)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  economy              region                year       EDBI_score
  <chr>                <chr>                 <date>          <dbl>
1 Brunei Darussalam    East Asia and Pacific 2010-01-01       60.8
2 Cambodia             East Asia and Pacific 2010-01-01       50.1
3 China                East Asia and Pacific 2010-01-01       56.5
4 Fiji                 East Asia and Pacific 2010-01-01       67.9
5 Hong Kong SAR, China East Asia and Pacific 2010-01-01       88.3
6 Indonesia            East Asia and Pacific 2010-01-01       56.8
```

I would like to plot as a line graph using ggplot2 such that `year` is on the x-axis whilst `EDBI_score` is on the y-axis. I have used this code:

```
plot <- ggplot(officialData, aes(x = year, y = EDBI_score, color = region))
plot + geom_line()
```

however this returns a graph in which point are connected horizontally as vertically.
[image]
I know this is because ggplot2 thinks that points should be grouped but I want to have every country (under the variable `economy`) mapped on my line graph and simply coloured according to `region`. Is this possible (I know it would be messy and horizontal lines will overlap) to do this without points being connected vertically?

Comment: Try adding `group = economy` to your `aes()` statement.

Comment: This works great thank you! I did try originally but it kept throwing an error (must have been a typo elsewhere).